# Unable to give network name in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a network in docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"
networks:
  frontend:
    name: custom_frontend
    driver: custom-driver-1
```

it is giving error : `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
networks.frontend value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)`

Please help

```
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
```

Comment: 1.17.1 only supports up to 3.4: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.17.1

Comment: use "docker compose" instead of "docker-compose", which need install docker-compose-plugin

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The compose file was fine. But as [jonrsharpe mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155523/unable-to-give-network-name-in-docker-compose#comment102693940_58155523), your `docker-compose` is not support version `3.5`.

[The releases page](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases)

You can run the following commands to upgrade `docker-compose` to `1.28.5`.

```sh
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.5/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

(The commands were copied from the releases page)

After upgrade, you can run `docker-compose -f <your-compose-file> config` to check whether the compose file is valid. If your compose file is valid it'll just print it out.

Comment: For me `1.24.1` didn't work. I upgraded it to current/latest version `1.27.4` and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.5/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/bin/docker-compose

Comment: I'm not sure when it changed, but now you need a "v" in front of the version number as in: ```curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.17.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose```